# Evaporation amount of water for a Storm

Tags: atmospheric-science, phase-transition, evaporation

How much water from the ocean is evaporated for a storm over water?

I am trying to figure out what conditions will cause the most evaporation or how to calculate the amount of water evaporated for a given storm.

Answer (score 0):

No vapour is needed to form a storm, only deep convection is required, there are storms on ice and on deserts but dont have any precipitation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_thunderstorm

the evaporation of ocean water in a wet storm is the same water in its rainfall

a number is for example 2.1 x 10^16 cubic centimeters